# Владение ресурсом через указатель

Tags: c++, winapi, unique-ptr, raii

Чтобы не заморачиваться с написанием класса-обертки, думаю использовать `лямбда + unique_ptr`, иначе говоря, пишу

```
HKEY key = nullptr;
auto regclose = [](HKEY *key) {
   if ((key) && *key != nullptr) {
      if (!RegCloseKey(*key))
        std::wcout << L"Не удалось закрыть ключ реестра" << std::endl;
   }
};
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Target", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key)) return 1;
std::unuque_ptr<HKEY, decltype(regclose)> halt(&key, regclose);
```

Насколько корректен будет этот код? Где потенциальные ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка тут в использовании указателя на объект с автоматическим временем хранения. Владение таким объектом не может быть передано в умный указатель. А владение объектом, на который ссылается дескриптор при таком подходе не передается.